# Extract Websites that end with .edu using R

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to look for websites that end with .edu and get the people's names. This is what i have so far and i am not sure how to proceed

```
library(stringr)

educational_institution = merged_data[str_sub((merged_data$Website),-3,-1) , c('LastName', 'FirstName','Website')]
head(educational_institution)
```

and I'm getting `NA` for results.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kskXT.png)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ronak mentioned in the comments it will be much easier to find a solution for you with a reproducible example (e.g. provide us with the `merged_data` object). Without that though, it looks like your issue is you aren't defining a logical vector within the square brackets. So if you're looking for all rows that end in 'edu' you need to add that logical statement with `== "edu"` See below for an example that could be what you're looking for.

```
library(stringr)

educational_institution <- merged_data[str_sub(merged_data$Website,-3,-1) == 'edu', c('LastName', 'FirstName','Website')]
head(educational_institution)
```

Or alternatively with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

educational_institution <- merged_data %>%
  filter(str_sub(Website, -3, -1) == 'edu') %>%
  select(LastName, FirstName, Website)
```